# Блицопрос, блиц-опрос? но блицкриг

Tags: дефис, раздельно, слитно

Блицопрос? Блиц-опрос, но блицкриг... Склоняюсь к дефису с «опросом», как-то странно писать его слитно... а блицкриг - заимствование с немецкого... Так?
Розенталь: «При колебаниях между дефисным и слитным написанием слов иноязычного происхождения предпочитается второе, если в русском языке в слове не выделяются составные части с присущим им значением, например: блиц-криг – блицкриг». «Не выделяются составные части с присущим им значением», то есть слово самостоятельно не употребляется?

Comment: Многоточия никогда четырьмя точками не пишутся.

Comment: у меня три точки..

Comment: Я убрал просто четвёртую в трёх местах.

Comment: Спасибо. Ваш ответ кто-то лайкнул...)

Comment: Странно, что-то не видно) И непонятно где)

Comment: Стоит единичка рядом с треугольником. Это считается лайком здесь?)

Comment: Ааа, я тупица, не понял, что вы про лайк к комментарию! Думал про ответы))

Answer (score 0):

В вопросах орфографии приоритет имеет орфографический словарь.
[Он утверждает однозначно](https://orfo.ruslang.ru/abc/part/be?start=11387&end=11687): **блицопрос**.

Comment: Не нравится мне этот словарь)....  А Розенталь Вам как??? «При колебаниях между дефисным и слитным написанием слов иноязычного происхождения предпочитается второе, если в русском языке в слове не выделяются составные части с присущим им значением, например: блиц-криг – блицкриг, ватер-машина – ватермашина, ватер-поло – ватерполо, гумми-арабик – гуммиарабик, метрд'о-тель – метрдотель, табльд'от – табльдот»....

Comment: @flossyU в науке (а лингвистика — это наука) нет понятий "нравится" или "не нравится".  Академический орфографический словарь "Академос" — нормативный, то есть именно он отражает современную орфографическую норму в  русском языке.

Comment: А Розенталя куда мы денем?

Comment: @flossyU "Нужно твердо помнить, что за справками орфографического характера следует обращаться только к орфографическому словарю" (А. Б. Шапиро, 1961). Справочники Розенталя понемногу устаревают, как устаревает любой справочник по живому языку. Поэтому в случае разночтения следует отдавать предпочтение более современным, а также более узконаправленным нормативным словарям и справочникам.

Comment: Меня всегда учили, что Розенталь – это наше все....

Comment: @flossyU сочувствую.

Comment: Право не стоит....

Comment: @flossyU  Я тоже считаю, что Розенталь –  это наше все. Но РОзенталь - это справочник по правописанию, а фактически – лучшее  и самое полное описание русской системы письма. Но есть еще орфографический словарь, которым распоряжается РАН. Они могут вносить изменение в написание отдельных слов. Иногда удачные, а иногда не очень. Все-таки современные академики  по уровню своих знаний не дотягивают до тех, кто составлял правила в 1956 году. Я полагаю, что блицопрос – это не самое лучшее их детище, особенно если судить по слиянию согласного и гласного.

Comment: В общем,  пока так: правила – это одно ведомство, а словарь –  другое. Но к сожалению, словарь официальный и его требования нужно исполнять.

Comment: @Sharon я не думаю, что русская система письма неизменна, кроме разве что самого-самого фундамента, вроде морфологического принципа.

Comment: Наша система письма  основана на принципах, и их можно считать постоянными.  В правилах описано их применение в различных темах, и это тоже наша основа основ, образец для развития. И вот для написания слов типа блиц-опрос больше подходит дефис, так как это приложение (быстрый опрос).

Comment: Еще интересно: Ответ справочной службы русского языка.

Главный редактор «Большого толкового словаря русского языка» С. А. Кузнецов настаивает на дефисном написании слов с первой частью блиц... Без его согласия мы не вправе вносить изменения в электронную версию.

Но общее правило: написание слов проверяется в первую очередь по орфографическому словарю. «Русский орфографический словарь» РАН дает: блицтурнир.

Comment: @Sharon я приводил выше цитату советского лингвиста. Он тоже говорил, что орфография сверяется по орфографическому словарю, а не по толковому.

Comment: Я  тоже об этом  же говорила. Просто далеко не всем лингвистам нравится такое решение.  И уж в любом случае формы написания должны быть одинаковыми, а не зависеть от вида словаря, как у нас.

Comment: @Sharon, язык меняется... Вы же прекрасно об этом знаете.

Comment: БЛИЦОПРОС... Смешное слово.  Кажется, что кто-то  чего-то просит.